# Obtener el valor de un elemento "a" desde jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML:

```
<a onclick="funcion(this)" value="4">Un Nombre</a>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script>
  function(elemento){
    console.log(elemento.value);
  }
</script>
```

esto me está devolviendo

> undefined

Comment: Desde jQuery o desde JavaScript?

Comment: jquery o javascript

Answer (score 6):

`value=""` no es un attributo válido para un enlace (anchor).

La forma correcta sería agregar un atributo `data-value`

```
<a onclick="mifuncion(this)" data-value="4">Un Nombre</a>
```

Aquí puedes ver los atributos específicos soportados por `<a>`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

También puedes ver los atributos globales que pueden ser incluidos en `<a>`: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes

---

Para obtener este atributo `data-value` por medio de jQuery, podemos usar el método [data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/) de jQuery pasando como parámetro el texto del nombre del atributo después de `data-`, te falta además definir la función (el nombre):

```
<script>
  function mifuncion(elemento) {
    console.log($(elemento).data('value'));
  }
</script>
```

---

Por medio de JavaScript vanilla es igual de fácil, con la diferencia que no hay una librería/framework externo, tan solo utilizamos la propiedad [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) y de nuevo el nombre del atributo después del texto `data-`:

```
<script>
  function mifuncion(elemento) {
    console.log(elemento.dataset.value);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: gracias señor, una cosa nueva que se aprende.

Answer (score 1):

El tag `<a>` no tiene un atributo value de forma estandar, puedes definirlo pero no es que cuente con uno

[HTML  Tag](http://HTML%20%3Ca%3E%20Tag)

veras que el value no es un atributo valido, pero igual con jquery podrias implementar

```js
$(function(){
     $('a').click(function(e){
       
          alert($(this).attr('value'));
       
       });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a value="4">Un Nombre</a>
```

Comment: ok, muchas gracias por la información.

Answer (score 1):

#### Desde JavaScript puro:

Hay que considerar:

1. El código javaScript debería estar presente ANTES que el documento se cargue para poder asignarle la función. Por lo tanto, el `<script>` debe estar accesible antes. Una forma fácil de solucionarlo es cargándolo en el `<head>`.
2. `value` no es una propiedad que pertenezca a `<a>`, por lo tanto, deberías recuperar el valor con [`.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute).
3. Te olvidaste de ponerle el nombre a la función. Podemos llamarla `MostrarValor`.

```js
function MostrarValor(elemento){
    console.log(elemento.getAttribute("value"));
}
```

```html
<a onclick="MostrarValor(this);" value="4">Un Nombre</a>
```

---

#### Con jQuery

De nuevo, cargándolo en el `<head>` y definiendo un nombre para la función. Esta vez, usamos [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```js
function MostrarValor(elemento){
    console.log($(elemento).attr("value"))
}
```

```html
<!-- Ponemos la referencia a jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Tu HTML -->
<a onclick="MostrarValor(this);" value="4">Un Nombre</a>
```

Comment: gracias, muy buena información.