# Como puedo mandar el id junto con un evento en js

Tags: javascript, html

mi duda es si puedo mandar el id de una etiqueta en html junto con el mismo evento que lo ejecuta, por ejemplo:

```
<button id="boton" onclick="mandarId()">
```

y que al suceder el evento mande el id de la etiqueta tambien.

Comment: te recomiendo que heches un vistazo a esto: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, pero no puedo usar librerias de js

Comment: @AlbertoMier No es necesario usar una librería entera para una sola utilidad. Es verdad que JQuery te ahorra mucho tiempo algunas veces pero hay que mirar también por intentar disminuir recursos :)

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Obtener el valor de un elemento "a" desde jQuery](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/19569/obtener-el-valor-de-un-elemento-a-desde-jquery)

Comment: @aldanux Realmente no sé si sería un duplicado exacto de esta pregunta. En esta específicamente hace referencia **solamente** a Javascript y en la otra solicita respuestas de JQuery. Sin embargo, si que es verdad que las respuestas que le dan están en javascript puro.

Answer (score 8):

Otra opcion, considerada una mejor practica, es utilizar *[javascript no obstructivo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_no_obstructivo)* (Unobtrusive JavaScript) que implica, entre otras cosas, separar la presentacion de funcionalidad.

Se trata de enlazar el evento desde javascript y no desde el HTML, con la ventaja (entre otras) de que siempre recibes el evento, en lugar de tener que estar pasando parametros. Como el evento tiene la informacion de quien recibio el mismo, esto puede aprovecharse para, por ejemplo, reutilizar manejadores (callbacks).

En el siguiente ejemplo, suponemos que tienes varios botones y dependiendo del ID quieres hacer una cosa u otra. Podrias hacer lo siguiente:

```js
// esta es la funcion que invocan todos los botones
function manejadorCallback(evento) {

  // cada vez que clickas un boton. Automaticamente se invoca con un parametro
  // que es el Evento. el cual tiene una propiedad (entre otras) llamada target
  // que es el elemento que dispara el evento. Luego buscas el id en target.
  alert(evento.target.id);  
}

// aqui el javascript no obstructivo.

// obtenemos todos los botones, por su clase
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.miboton')

// a cada uno le asignamos el manejador del evento.
for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {

   // aqui generas el equivalente a onclick
   buttons[i].addEventListener('click', manejadorCallback);
}
```

```html
<button id="elid" class="miboton">Presiona</button>
<button id="otroid" class="miboton">Presiona</button>
<button id="masIds" class="miboton">Presiona</button>
```

Comment: Sabía que esto se podía hacer y lo he buscado pero no sabía como y por eso he puesto la más rápida y sencilla. Muy buena tu respuesta :)

Comment: Yo prefiero esta opcion igual. El codigo es mucho mas claro cuando se separa javascript del html.

Comment: muy buena respuesta heheh yo fui a lo rapido xD

Answer (score 3):

Lo puedes hacer pasándole `this.id` en la función, donde `this` hace referencia al objeto al que le estás haciendo click.

```js
function mandarId(id){
  alert(id);
 }
```

```html
<button id="boton" onclick="mandarId(this.id)">click aquí </button>
```

Comment: woo gano con 6 segundos de diferencia muahahah xD yo pasaria `this` solo, aunque esté buscando el `id` porque con `this` puede sacar mucha mas informacion si se necesitase.

Comment: @lois6b Por una vez fuiste más rápido jajaja. Sí, podría pasar todo el elemento entero pero como en este caso especificaba que quería pasar el id por eso fui tan específico xD

Comment: asi es, se pedia el ID. Iba a responder, solo que 4 horas mas tarde, jejeje

Answer (score 2):

Si pasas como parametro, `this` estás pasando la información de aquello a lo que llama la funcion (en este caso el boton) para asi poder obtener su `id`por ejemplo

```js
  
  function mandarId(elem){
    alert(elem.id);
    
    }
```

```html
<button id="boton" onclick="mandarId(this)"> Click </button>
```