# Haciendo una calculadora: ¿Que es lo que falta en este bucle?

Tags: javascript

Quiero que cada vez que se pulse en una tecla (en cualquier < button > con la clase " key ") el numero se añada a el input

```html
<div id="calculator">
        <div class="calc_keys"> 
          <input class="input" id="input0" value="5"; type="text" name="fname">
          <button class="operator suma">+</button>
          <button class="operator resta">-</button>
          <button class="operator mult">*</button>
          <button class="operator div">/</button>
          <button value="7" class="key">7</button>
          <button  value="8" class="key">8</button>
          <button  value="9" class="key">9</button>
          <button  value="4" class="key">4</button>
          <button  value="5" class="key">5</button>
          <button  value="6" class="key">6</button>
          <button  value="1" class="key">1</button>
          <button  value="2" class="key">2</button>
          <button  value="3" class="key">3</button>
          <button  value="0" class="cero">0</button>
          <button class="punto">.</button>
          <button id="borrar" class="borrar">Borrar</button>
          <button class="igual">=</button>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Entonces he hecho esto:

```js
/* VAR RESULTADO */
var input0 = document.getElementById("input0");

var teclas = document.querySelectorAll('.key');

function add(){
    input0.value = teclas.value;
  }

for (var i = 0 ; i < teclas.length; i++) {
    teclas[i].addEventListener('click' , add ) ; 
 }
```

Con el ultimo bucle si pulso cualquier tecla con la clase " key " me aparece en el input "undefined". He probado a poner teclas.value en la declaración de variable pero entonces da el error " Cannot read property 'length' of undefined "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.querySelectorAll('.key')` retorna un array con los elementos que tengan la clase `.key` y claramente un array no tiene una propiedad `value`.

Intenta utilizando el `event` en el metodo `add` y con la propiedad `target.value` accedes al valor del boton que se le hizo click:

```js
/* VAR RESULTADO */
var input0 = document.getElementById("input0");

var teclas = document.querySelectorAll('.key');

function add(e){

    input0.value = e.target.value;
}

for (var i = 0 ; i < teclas.length; i++) {
    teclas[i].addEventListener('click' , add ) ; 
 }
```

```html
<div id="calculator">
        <div class="calc_keys"> 
          <input class="input" id="input0" value="5"; type="text" name="fname">
          <button class="operator suma">+</button>
          <button class="operator resta">-</button>
          <button class="operator mult">*</button>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
          <button class="operator div">/</button>
          <button value="7" class="key">7</button>
          <button  value="8" class="key">8</button>
          <button  value="9" class="key">9</button>
          <button  value="4" class="key">4</button>
          <button  value="5" class="key">5</button>
          <button  value="6" class="key">6</button>
          <button  value="1" class="key">1</button>
          <button  value="2" class="key">2</button>
          <button  value="3" class="key">3</button>
          <button  value="0" class="cero">0</button>
          <button class="punto">.</button>
          <button id="borrar" class="borrar">Borrar</button>
          <button class="igual">=</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Vamos por partes:

1. Si te fijas, tu variable `teclas` tiene un [listado de nodos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) con los botones de la calculadora. Si muestras por consola `teclas.value` verás que es `undefined` porque no estás accediendo a ningún botón en concreto:

```js
var teclas = document.querySelectorAll('.key');

console.log(teclas);
```

```html
<div id="calculator">
        <div class="calc_keys"> 
          <input class="input" id="input0" value="5"; type="text" name="fname">
          <button class="operator suma">+</button>
          <button class="operator resta">-</button>
          <button class="operator mult">*</button>
          <button class="operator div">/</button>
          <button value="7" class="key">7</button>
          <button  value="8" class="key">8</button>
          <button  value="9" class="key">9</button>
          <button  value="4" class="key">4</button>
          <button  value="5" class="key">5</button>
          <button  value="6" class="key">6</button>
          <button  value="1" class="key">1</button>
          <button  value="2" class="key">2</button>
          <button  value="3" class="key">3</button>
          <button  value="0" class="cero">0</button>
          <button class="punto">.</button>
          <button id="borrar" class="borrar">Borrar</button>
          <button class="igual">=</button>
        </div>
      </div>
```

2. El hecho de declarar `teclas` como una variable global hace que sea accesible dentro de la función `add` pero esto es una muy mala práctica ya que puede haber conflictos con otras variables o métodos ([aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/106042/var-let-const-o-nada-en-javascript/106067#106067) más info sobre `var`, `let` y `const`)
3. Ya que estás llamando a la función `add` dentro del `for` en el que ya estás recorriendo `teclas` lo ideal es que le pases el valor del botón pulsado a la función `add`. Para ello simplemente pásale el valor de `this.value` ya que `this` en ese contexto hace referencia al `teclas[i]` correspondiente. Además, ten en cuenta que o bien puedes pasarle **la referencia** a la función encapsulando la llamada con `function(){...}` (te pongo este ejemplo):

```js
/* VAR RESULTADO */
var input0 = document.getElementById("input0");

var teclas = document.querySelectorAll('.key');

function add(val){
    input0.value = val;
  }

for (var i = 0 ; i < teclas.length; i++) {
    teclas[i].addEventListener('click' , function(){add(this.value)}) ; 
 }
```

```html
<div id="calculator">
        <div class="calc_keys"> 
          <input class="input" id="input0" value="5"; type="text" name="fname">
          <button class="operator suma">+</button>
          <button class="operator resta">-</button>
          <button class="operator mult">*</button>
          <button class="operator div">/</button>
          <button value="7" class="key">7</button>
          <button  value="8" class="key">8</button>
          <button  value="9" class="key">9</button>
          <button  value="4" class="key">4</button>
          <button  value="5" class="key">5</button>
          <button  value="6" class="key">6</button>
          <button  value="1" class="key">1</button>
          <button  value="2" class="key">2</button>
          <button  value="3" class="key">3</button>
          <button  value="0" class="cero">0</button>
          <button class="punto">.</button>
          <button id="borrar" class="borrar">Borrar</button>
          <button class="igual">=</button>
        </div>
      </div>
```

O bien jugar con el evento (como en este ejemplo. [Aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/31738/como-puedo-mandar-el-id-junto-con-un-evento-en-js) más info):

```js
/* VAR RESULTADO */
var input0 = document.getElementById("input0");

var teclas = document.querySelectorAll('.key');

function add(event){  
    input0.value = event.target.value;
  }

for (var i = 0 ; i < teclas.length; i++) {
    teclas[i].addEventListener('click' , add) ; 
 }
```

```html
<div id="calculator">
        <div class="calc_keys"> 
          <input class="input" id="input0" value="5"; type="text" name="fname">
          <button class="operator suma">+</button>
          <button class="operator resta">-</button>
          <button class="operator mult">*</button>
          <button class="operator div">/</button>
          <button value="7" class="key">7</button>
          <button  value="8" class="key">8</button>
          <button  value="9" class="key">9</button>
          <button  value="4" class="key">4</button>
          <button  value="5" class="key">5</button>
          <button  value="6" class="key">6</button>
          <button  value="1" class="key">1</button>
          <button  value="2" class="key">2</button>
          <button  value="3" class="key">3</button>
          <button  value="0" class="cero">0</button>
          <button class="punto">.</button>
          <button id="borrar" class="borrar">Borrar</button>
          <button class="igual">=</button>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Personalmente me gusta más la primera opción pero para gustos los colores :)