# pasar el id de una etiqueta padre a una etiqueta hijo

Tags: javascript, jquery

mi pregunta es similar a esta...
[Obtener el valor de un elemento “a” desde jQuery](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/19569/obtener-el-valor-de-un-elemento-a-desde-jquery)

Quisiera saber, cómo pasar el atributo `id` de un `div` padre a un `buttom` hijo para ejecutar un metodo de `JQuery` donde necesito este parametro?

O si alguien puede ayudarme a como crear etiquetas o tag como por ejemplo las que se pueden colocar aqui. Solo la parte visual de las etiquetas, el encontrar las palabras relacionadas ya lo tengo

```
function quitarEtiqueta(id) {
var parent = id.parentNode;
alarm(parent.attr('id'));
};
```

este es mi codigo pero no logro obtener el id

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?, por favor  lee [ask], considera editar y agregar lo que llevas

Comment: Hola, no logro comprender exactamente lo que necesitas.¿puedes poner un ejemplo de el resultado que deseas obtener?

Answer (score 2):

No logro entender bien. Te puse 2 ejemplos.

Puedes setear cuantos datos quieras en la propiedad data de los elementos.

Ejemplo: data-loquequieras="suValor".

Después, pasas el botón como parámetro en el método para poder acceder a su propiedad "dataset".

También puedes acceder a las propiedades del div padre desde el hijo.

Código:

```js
function ActionDataset(btn){
  const idDiv = btn.dataset.idpadre
  console.log(idDiv)
}

function ActionParent(btn){
  const idDiv = btn.parentElement.getAttribute("id")
  console.log(idDiv)
}
```

```html
<div id="idDelDiv">
  <button onclick="ActionDataset(this)" id="btn" data-idPadre="idDelDiv">Prueba Dataset</button>
  
   <button onclick="ActionParent(this)" id="btn" data-idPadre="idDelDiv">Prueba Parent</button>
</div>
```